# is it possible to create a irregular window using electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I want to use electron and js to  create a desktop soft,but my soft don't need atom like [whose window is a large box],so is it possible to create a irregular window using electron？

[large box demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vINcp.png)

[irregular window demo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdhO0.jpg)

[irregular window demo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyCAJ.jpg)

Comment: Try reword your question please, it's very unclear. However, you probably looking for a [_frameless_ window](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do both those with electron by setting `frameless: true` and `transparent: true`.

`frameless: true` Gets rid of the window chrome (or the frame).

`transparent: true` Makes the window transparent.

For your 2nd image all you need to do is put a transparent image in the html page and set: `frameless: true`, `transparent: true`.

For your last image you would only need to set `frameless: true`.

[Frame less window docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/frameless-window/)

[Transparent window docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/frameless-window/#transparent-window)